# List of mostly all quotation marks used

Tags: symbols, punctuation

I'm seeking of a list of quotation marks used in different language. So far I found only this [wiki-page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-English_usage_of_quotation_marks). But there is only the marks itself in Unicode.

I know about [`csquotes`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/csquotes) package. I just want to find a list of all this marks as a LaTeX "commands", like `,,`, `<<` etc.

Comment: See the accepted answer of [How to look up a symbol?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14/how-to-look-up-a-symbol), especially tables 2, 8 and 40 in `symbols-a4.pdf` / `symbols-letter.pdf`. Also very informative: table 6 in documentation for package `csquotes` “Quotation Marks Provided by Encodings T1, LY1, EU1/EU2”.